# Detect if string contains any element of a string array

Tags: arrays, swift, string

How would I detect if a string contains any member of an array of strings (words)?

Here is the array:

```
let str:String = "house near the beach"
 let wordGroups:[String] = ["beach","waterfront","with a water view","near ocean","close to water"]
```

The following is not compiling

```
let match:Bool = wordGroups.contains(where: str.contains)
```

Comment: Your code compiles for me (and returns `true`).  What error are you getting?

Comment: 'Call can throw but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled' plus an unwrapping error.The compiler eventually accepted let match:Bool = self.wordGroups.contains(where: (str?.contains)!)

Comment: There's nothing in the question that should throw or need to be unwrapped, so I assume your real code is a little different and the problem is somewhere else.  Be careful unless you're absolutely 100% certain `str` will never be nil.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In additional to answer of @Sh_Khan, if you want match some word from group:

```
let str:String = "house near the beach"
let wordGroups:[String] = ["beach","waterfront","with a water view","near ocean","close to water"]
let worlds = wordGroups.flatMap { $0.components(separatedBy: " ")}
let match = worlds.filter { str.range(of:$0) != nil }.count != 0
```

Answer (score 14):

I am using **String** extension:

```
extension String {
    func contains(_ strings: [String]) -> Bool {
        strings.contains { contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
let str = "house near the beach"
let wordGroups = ["beach","waterfront", "with a water view", "near ocean", "close to water"]
let haveWord = str.contains(wordGroups)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try

```
let str = Set("house near the beach")
let match = wordGroups.filter { str.contains($0) }.count != 0
```