# Determine which word from an array of strings appears first in a text block in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string

I have an array of strings which can be either words or phrases in no particular order:

```
searchWords = ["December", "Wednesday", "beginning of winter", "Thursday", "summer solstice"]
```

I also have a block of text

```
text = "This year the start of the summer solstice will be on a Wednesday.  And the beginning of winter will start on a Thursday."
```

What I would like to do is determine which word or phrase in the string array is the first word or phrase to appear in the text block.  In the example above the desired method would return "summer solstice".

How can I accomplish this?

I found this related question, but the suggestions provided only return a boolean indicating that one of the words was found, not the actual first word found ([Detect if string contains any element of a string array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711049/detect-if-string-contains-any-element-of-a-string-array))

Comment: What have you tried so far, where do you struggle? With short texts like these that don't really require super-optimized solution, there's several straight-forward ways to solve this.

Comment: Quickly written, not fully tested: `let firstOccurence = searchWords.min(by: { first, second in guard let firstLowerBound = text.range(of: first)?.lowerBound else { return false }; guard let secondLowerBound = text.range(of: second)?.lowerBound else { return true }; return firstLowerBound < secondLowerBound })`

Comment: @DarkDust I tried just looping through the words in the array and keeping track of the lowest index number. I was hoping there might be something more compact and efficient than the approach I took. Larme, I'll take a look at the code you provided and see if I can understand how that would work.

Comment: @Larme, I tried your solution and it does seem to work when there is a word in the word list that can be found in the text block.  So thanks for that.  But if no words in the word list appear in the text block (a possibility I didn’t mention), it returns the first word in the word list, even though that word is not in the text block.  I'm not doing too well with my first post to Stack Overflow (3 down votes in the first hour) so I don't want to violate any more site norms.  Not sure where to go from here (maybe delete my post), but thought I would add this comment first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following algorithm:

1. convert the array of words to a dictionary holding the position of the words:

```swift
let positions = searchWords
    .reduce(into: [:]) { dict, word in dict[word] = text.range(of: word)?.lowerBound }
```

2. find out the key with the minimum value:

```swift
let minPositionWord = positions.min { $0.1 < $1.1 }?.key
```

Or, in one piece:

```swift
let word = searchWords
    .reduce(into: [:]) { dict, word in dict[word] = text.range(of: word)?.lowerBound }
    .min { $0.1 < $1.1 }?.key
```

Comment: Thank you @DarkDust and Cristik for taking the time to answer my question.  I appreciate it.  Both responses use similar approaches and perform fast, so either could be used.  I'm marking Cristik's response as the solution as I find it easy to understand in one glance.  It reads so nicely.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this:

```
import Foundation

let searchWords = ["December", "Wednesday", "beginning of winter", "Thursday", "summer solstice"]
let text = "This year the start of the summer solstice will be on a Wednesday.  And the beginning of winter will start on a Thursday."

func findFirstTerm(of searchWords: [String], in text: String) -> String? {
    let terms: [(term: String, index: String.Index)] = searchWords.compactMap {
        guard let lowerBound = text.range(of: $0)?.lowerBound else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return ($0, lowerBound)
    }
    
    return terms.min(by: {
        $0.index < $1.index
    })?.term
}


print(findFirstTerm(of: searchWords, in: text)) // Optional("summer solstice")
print(findFirstTerm(of: searchWords, in: "text")) // nil
```

First, it collects all terms and their position in the text, discarding the ones that don't appear in the text. From this list of matches, the one with the lowest index is picked.